# Android mechanical switching event detection

Tags: android, event-handling, hardware-interface

Thanks for your help in advance: on some rare android devices, there are mechanical switches, for example, the lid open switch, a flashlight popping-up switch in Galaxy camera. Our question is how do we, using android SDK, capture these mechanical switching event. for the life of me, I can not find any callbacks that deals with hardware switching events via SDK. In addition, how do we check the binary switch_state of these switches? Any suggestion is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: Pretty much by definition, you will need to ask a device manufacturer about how to find out about events for hardware that is peculiar to their device.

Comment: I see, thanks CommonsWare, is it fare to say that there aint much hope from SDK side?

Comment: You can see if you can get source code for the builds on the devices.  You can run logcat while actuating the switch and see what shows up.  And you can see if anything is exposed under /proc or /sys